# How to detect the visual height of a user's browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the min-height of a wrapper div dynamically based on the height of the visible portion of a user's monitor. How can this be detected? I can then take this info and do something like this:

```
$('div.wrapper').css('min-height', 'MAGIC_AMOUNT_HEREpx');
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there's the `window.screen` object.  See [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml) for details about it.  If you're just looking for the size of the visible area in the browser window, try `window.innerHeight`.

I think you can probably use jQuery for that, but I'd just use regular JavaScript because it's just as clean, if not cleaner, in this instance.

EDIT:

Another note, there are two jquery functions:

- `$(window).height()`
- `$(window).innerHeight()`

I think these both do the same thing, but neither return the monitor's height. I would use the native properties instead:

- `window.screen.availHeight`- gets the screen height minus taskbar and other stuff
- `window.screen.height`- gets the entire screen height

Worst case scenario, window.screen.height === window.screen.availHeight.

Answer (score 0):

try to calculate height using

```
$(window).height();
```

Comment: From jquery's website: `returns height of browser viewport`.  This sounds like it's just the visible area in the browser window not the monitor size.

Comment: yes, why do you want the monitor's height. if you want to set min-height then you should look for bowser's view-port.

Comment: He said monitor in the question. That's what I'm going off of.

Comment: in this case use window.screen.height, as tjameson mentioned in his answer